# Python bottle strange blocks

Tags: python, bottle

I've just recieved a new project on Python, using Bottle, a project without any documentation.

I can't make this project work (500 internal error). I recieve a SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Last traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 3252, in co
  return compile(self.code, self.filename or '<string>', 'exec')
File "/opt_host/web/src/views/homepage.tpl", line 102
  for (var star = 0; star < hotel.rating; star++) {
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone explain this (homepage.tpl):

```
<p class="star-rating" title="<%=hotel.rating%> Stars">
<% for (var star = 0; star < hotel.rating; star++) { %>
    <span class="star">&#9733;</span>
<% } %>
</p>
```

Maybe I forgot some depedencies or something?

Comment: I forget to say, that REAL project works, but customer have no idea how previous developer deployed it and have no access to real server (only for domains).

Comment: If your project is using bottle's template, that piece of code is trying to embed python code and obviously it's not valid. Check the docs http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#embedded-python-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the project is using the javascript [underscore template](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer. The problem was with the version of bottle - it turns out that 0.11.xx versions do not handle tags '<%' and they work fine with the underscore js.

Answer (score 1):

That is not python syntax at all.  I don't know Bottle but taking a quick look at it's docs I can't see any suggestion that it takes syntax like this.

A for loop in Python would look like:

```
for star in range(hotel.rating):
```

It looks as if a line of Javascript or something similar has been dropped in where it should be python.